# Video (SKYPE) facility in YII

Tags: yii

I am trying to build a framework for integrating SKYPE functionality (online video chatting) with intranet.  My preference is to go with YII.  Has anybody done this?

Any pointers your can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time